# IScreenshotProvider.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version

Tags: android

I am using a java code(using asl library) for screen capturing of my mobile, but after
modification i am getting an error how to fix it?

```
IScreenshotProvider.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
```

Answer (score 0):

`IScreenshotProvider.java` looks like to be a system generated file and should not be modified manually.

In this case, you cant edit it simply.